# Web Crawler for Linked Data in Java with Jena Library

Tags: web-crawler, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I have to implement a Web Cralwer that visits the Linked Data on the Web. I have built a simple functionality for that. I have three queries for that:

1. What are the seed URIs I should use. The web sites which provide data in RDF format and follow Tim Berners Lee [Linked Data principles](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html) ??
2. Generally what do you mean by round based approach for Web-Cralwers? I read about general       Web Crawlers and found that round based approach should be followed.
3. I am able to parse only web pages which can return RDF/XML data .Is it sufficient to crawl the Linked Data.

Answer (score 5):

1. There's a couple of options, for example use all the URIs found in the [Billion Triples Challenge dump](http://km.aifb.kit.edu/projects/btc-2012/) as starting points, or all the resources listed in the [lodcloud group on the Data Hub](http://thedatahub.org/group/lodcloud) (can be retrieved through the [CKAN API](http://wiki.ckan.org/API)).
2. Sorry, I don't know.
3. No, RDF/XML is not sufficient, as many datasets published as linked data use other formats. You also want [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) and [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/). You can use [Apache Any23](http://any23.apache.org/), which understands all of the above. [LDSpider](http://code.google.com/p/ldspider/) is a crawler that uses Any23.